# WHERE or HAVING to return an aggregation by customer_id in SQL

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, where-clause, having

I'm looking for the maximum purchase amount order in the range 50$ and 200$ by combination of each customer and order date.

For 2 different queries I don't have the result set, so I don't understand the difference between WHERE and HAVING to filter.

Query 1: WHERE clause

```
SELECT id, order_date, MAX(price)
FROM orders
WHERE price BETWEEN 50 AND 200
GROUP BY id;
```

Query 2: HAVING clause

```
SELECT id, order_date, MAX(price)
FROM orders
GROUP BY id
HAVING MAX(price) BETWEEN 50 AND 200
```

Result for Query 1:

```
id  order_date  MAX(price)
1   2013-01-10  103.50
5   2013-01-01  195.50
6   2013-01-01  172.50
8   2013-01-01  147.20
9   2013-01-01  165.60
10  2013-01-01  184.00
12  2013-01-18  191.40
24  2013-01-02  138.00
25  2013-01-07  100.63
26  2013-01-16  86.71
30  2013-01-03  155.25
35  2013-01-08  96.60
36  2013-01-02  169.74
40  2013-01-03  197.80
45  2013-01-02  124.20
48  2013-01-02  149.04
50  2013-01-03  157.55
52  2013-01-03  173.42
60  2013-01-03  186.30
75  2013-01-02  181.13
100 2013-01-04  147.20
125 2013-01-04  184.00
```

Result for Query 2:

```
id  order_date  MAX(price)
25  2013-01-03  100.63
26  2013-01-16  86.71
35  2013-01-08  96.60
45  2013-01-02  124.20
52  2013-01-03  173.42
```

It seems that it's the result of the HAVING clause query that is expected and I don't understand why or even what the differences are in between the 2 queries.

Comment: Take a closer look at an id returned by q1 but not q2. E.g. id = 100. What do you see? (I.e. do `select id, price from orders where id = 100`.)

Comment: I have all the purchase dates and purchase prices for customer_id 100

Comment: And the highest price is?

Comment: higher price is 12880 without any filter and 147,20 for the range(50,200). But multiple customer_id with the same price. the date is unique for couple id and price

Comment: Now you can see the difference between query 1 and 2. If you want the maximum value within a range, use WHERE. If you want a user whose highest value is within a range, use HAVING.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the WHERE clause limits the selected rows to those in the specified range, the MAX(price) will definitely be in that range because the WHERE excludes all rows whose price is < 50 or > 200.

The HAVING clause, however, is applied after the MAX is selected. If a row has a MAX(price) either < 50 or > 200 it is excluded by the HAVING clause.

Which one is right I don't know, because I don't know your requirement. You'll have to decide that.

Added later:

If you have one customer with 4 transactions on the same day at prices 10, 100, 150, and 500 then:
`WHERE price BETWEEN 50 AND 200` will pick out the 100 and 150 transactions. The `GROUP BY` will pick out the 150 and drop the 100.

Similarly, without the WHERE the query will pick all 4 transactions, and then the `GROUP BY` will pick the 500 and drop the other 3. Finally the `HAVING` will drop the 500 and have nothing left to show.

Put in a few day's worth of data shaped like that and then play with various WHERE's and HAVING's, and see what happens when you have both. You need to play about with this stuff to get used to it.

And I still can't tell you what you want when you have 4 prices as I've used. You have to decide what you want and then write the query to get it.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I can't see really the point. I can't say which one to pick because I can't get the HAVING clause process :/ In my mind both should give the same result

Comment: I tried similar queries but now I have the same result for both except the date:

`SELECT id, order_date, MAX(price)
FROM orders
WHERE price > 10000
GROUP BY id;`
 and 
`SELECT id, order_date, MAX(price)
FROM orders
GROUP BY id
HAVING MAX(price) > 10000;`

Why now there are same id and price returned?

Comment: @Lilly_Co Since the two versions are doing different things there should be different results. Say a customer had 4 transactions on one day with prices 10, 100, 150, and 500. The WHERE version should show 150; the HAVING version should show nothing as max(price) would be 500. If you have both the WHERE and the HAVING in one statement, it would show 150. The WHERE is doing something different to the HAVING so it's not a surprise they have different results.

Comment: @Lilly_Co: Expanded the answer. I'm not sure there's much I can add after this.